# how to animate android listview item when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to implement a new feature.when user scroll the listview up,each item will show a animation,I notice the android supply layout animation,but it will animate only four situation:

> ```
> APPEARING - A flag indicating the animation that runs on items that are appearing in the container.
> CHANGE_APPEARING - A flag indicating the animation that runs on items that are changing due to a new item appearing in the container.
> DISAPPEARING - A flag indicating the animation that runs on items that are disappearing from the container.
> CHANGE_DISAPPEARING - A flag indicating the animation that runs on items that are changing due to an item disappearing from the
> ```
>
> container.

But how can I make the items which have appeared animate during I scroll the listview.The feature is same with the htc sence5 BlinkFeed,when it scrolls,it will animate each item.

Comment: did you get any help ??